# 'resolver must resolve module reference to a valid module' message in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, service-reference

Getting message 'resolver must resolve module reference to a valid module' in VS 2012 every time I right-click a Service Reference and choose Configure Service Reference.
I have no idea what could it be and will be grateful for any help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help, it fixed my problem.

> In the project file I had several other services too which were producing the same error when trying to configure the services. By trial and error I updated one of the service references which must of been corrupt, as I am now able configure my other services.

ref: http://forums.asp.net/t/1836029.aspx/1

Comment: Looks like a good solution. I didn't figure the reason of my problem.
My solution was a simple recreation of my project.